# Trying to vertically append images with ImageMagick in terminal

Tags: imagemagick

Typing this:

```
convert -append IMG1.jpg IMG2.jpg IMG3.jpg IMG4.jpg IMG5.jpg out.jpg
```

I get this error:

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
convert: no images defined `out.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3288.
```

Comment: All .jpg working. I double click on each and they open. Each image is about 1 mb though, I don't know if that is the issue but it shouldn't be ...

Comment: Just resized <100kb but still same error. Wonder if I ImageMagick install properly?

Comment: Looks ok to me. https://i.imgur.com/LdAfal6.png still not sure what is going on

Comment: Do other `convert` commands work properly?

Comment: Not only 'convert' doesn't work but others too like 'display' command. Very strange. So I unistalled and reinstalled again, with small sizes but still nothing. https://i.imgur.com/Oulkyyf.png

Comment: I resorted to using gimp to append them but it was odd that imagemagick couldn't work. Thank you.